# Drop event not firing/triggering in JS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, event-handling

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/u3m4eazx/

I have 2 images that are draggable and 3 divs where you can drop the images ($dropZones).

```
$dropZones.forEach($z => {
  $z.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver);
  $z.addEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave);
  $z.addEventListener('drop', onDrop);
});
```

The dragover and dragleave events trigger and work perfectly. I do a hover effect to the div by adding a css class.

```
const onDragOver = e => {
  e.preventDefault;
  let id = e.target.dataset.id;
  let dropzone = document.querySelector(`.dropzone[data-id="${id}"]`);
  dropzone.classList.add('ready');
};
```

And in the dragleave event I just remove the class. So they work well.
But the drop event doesn't fire up. This is what I have in the drop event

```
const onDrop = e => {
  console.log("Drop triggered");
  alert('Drop triggered');
};
```

Anyone knows why the event doesn't trigger?

Comment: @Downgoat I'm I not allowed to greet the people? lol

Comment: [See this post describing "Hello"s](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/204010)

Comment: Simple human logic: It's just polite if you greet people who are willing to help you. Anyway thanks for the effort.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use ES6? If not, it's not a problem with ES6 (and I don't see why it should be).

Comment: No it also doesn't work without ES6. Maybe I should've removed the es6 tag, that would make more sense I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah so I looked back at this and found out that the `preventDefault()` function is written wrong. 
I wrote it without `()`. 
Thanks anyway.